# porque no me aparece la flecha o boton para regresar al mainpage principal en xamarinforms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

estoy llendo del maipage principal a otro contentpage de la siguiente manera:

```html
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new brigadas()));
        }
```

Si me abre el contentpage pero no me aparece el boton para regresar.
asi es como sale, marco en rojo donde debe salir la flecha o boton para regresar pero no me aparece.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usndo visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema era que no estaba yo especificando cual era mi contentpage principal por lo tanto no podia regresar si abria yo el contentpage2 etc, especifique en App.xaml.css de la solucion lo siguiente:

```html
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = MainPage = new NavigationPage( new MainPage());
        }
```

y ahora si me aparece la flecha de retornar y en el evento del boton solo agregue:

```html
private async void btnbrig_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new brigadas());
        }
```

Saludos y espero que a alguien mas le ayude mi solucion.
PD: Nada que ver con los framework como lo menciona la otra respuesta dada.